# jetty - noSuchMethodError

Tags: maven-2, jetty, nosuchmethoderror

I get the following error when running `mvn jetty:run-war`:

```
2009-11-14 15:19:28.459:/:INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
* ERROR 15:19:28,491 Context initialization failed (ContextLoader.java [main])
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;)V
...
```

(Not including the whole stacktrace)

I know that there is nothing wrong with the code as it works perfectly fine both in Windows and OSX. Right now Im using Ubuntu karmic koala and installed maven through apt-get, could there be something that I have forgotten to configure in linux to make it work? I dont get any errors when doing mvn clean install.

Anyone?

Comment: Maybe you're not using the same versions of the Spring framework.

Comment: But, how can I have two different versions of the spring framework when this dependency is specified in my pom.xml files? I mean.. it works on all the other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a compatibility mismatch somewhere. Maybe your local repository contains a "stale" version of some jar. I'd suggest to retry with a fresh and clean local repository.

First, make a backup copy:

```
mv ~/.m2/repository ~/.m2/repository.save
```

Then, try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with local repository.
I guess your maven repo would have stored like root/.m2/repository
Old jar may be the issue

I guess you have written Jetty depandencies like below

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>WebContent</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <!-- <classesDirectory>WebContent/WEB-INF/classes</classesDirectory> -->
                <!-- Redeploy every 1 seconds if changes are detected, 0 for no automatic 
                    redeployment -->
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <!-- reload manually by hitting enter on console -->
                <reload>manual</reload>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/</contextPath>
                    <descriptor>WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                </webApp>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Check if the the "mvn install" is a Sucess then run Jetty.